# cx_Freeze: "No module named 'codecs'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

I've been desperately trying to compile my python pygame program into standalone executables to no prevail. PyInstaller doesn't work properly with pygame, Nuitka doesn't make standalones that work and cx_Freeze is looking the best choice. However, when I compile using my `setup.py`, it makes a set of files but the `main` executable doesn't run.

My `setup.py` is as below:

```
import sys
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py")]
images =["assets/images/1.png","assets/images/2.png","assets/images/3.png","assets/images/4.png","assets/images/5.png","assets/images/6.png","assets/images/7.png","assets/images/8.png","assets/images/tile.png","assets/images/mark.png","assets/images/mine.png","assets/images/overlay.png","assets/images/overlay_2.png","assets/images/background.png"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Minesweeper",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":images}},
    executables = executables

)
```

There are other python files that are referenced to by `main.py`; does this matter?

Many thanks

Edit:
As requested, platform is Linux (Ubuntu 14.04); python version is 3.4.3; cx_Freeze is cxfreeze 5.0, downloaded through pip. The exact error reads:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What platform? What version of cx_Freeze? What version of Python? What exception (and call stack) are you getting? As long as main.py imports the other Python files with a regular import statement the other files should be found and included automatically.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Appended to question. If you need any more information, just ask

Comment: Ubuntu has a modified Python which conflicts with cx_Freeze, I believe. If you build your own Python instead the problem should go away. If that is the case, please let me know. I'll see if I can get a Ubuntu setup to test on my end as well.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga okay, thanks but im not sure exactly how i'd do that. i've found workarounds using other software for now. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with cx_Freeze 5.0.1, python 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 15.10. As suggested by @Anthony Tuininga, reinstalling python from the source fixed the problem, for instance from [this source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-python-3-4-4-on-ubuntu) :

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.4.4.tgz

# I had to specify the location of zlib in my case
cd Python-3.4.4
./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo make altinstall
```

Then, I installed [cx_Freeze](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/releases) from source :

```
wget https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/archive/5.0.1.tar.gz
tar xzf 5.0.1.tar.gz
cd ./cx_Freeze-5.0.1/
python3.4 setup.py build
sudo python3.4 setup.py install
```

I also installed [pygame](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases) from source (as you are using it too) :

```
wget https://github.com/pygame/pygame/archive/1.9.3.tar.gz
tar xzf 1.9.3.tar.gz
cd ./pygame-1.9.3/
python3.4 setup.py build
sudo python3.4 setup.py install
```

Comment: ill take your word for it! thanks for the instructions too:)