# Error while creating executables using cx_Freeze on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert a very basic code to exe.

---

I am using Python 3.6, and I installed `cx_Freeze 5.1` using the pip command. It installed correctly. I made the `setup.py` file, and put it and the code in the Python directory.

When I ran the command "`python xyz.py build`" it started the build process, and completed it without any error. When I tried to run the executable file of my code, I get an error.

> Fatal Python error: Py-Initialize: unable to load the file system codec.
>   Traceback......line 31 in  ImportError: No Module named "codecs"

Comment: so seems like there is a module missing. maybe have a look on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs) - if it´s the same problem or solved give feedback.

Comment: What kind of OperatingSystem have you used? Paths/names can be changed on Windows/linux or not supported. Check the module-path and give feedback.

Comment: I am using Windows 8. I tried reinstalling Python, but it doesn't work. What do you mean by module-path?

Comment: reinstall `cx_Freeze 5.1`(maybe python too) and get this one `cx_Freeze-6.0b1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` and new python version. This seems to be working for some others.

Comment: There was a report-ticket for this issue and it got fiexed. just update everything.