# Python cx_Freeze __init__ "no module named codecs"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

When I run my compiled program (cx_Freeze) it says `__init__line 31. no module named codecs`.

I have Python 3.6, does anybody know why it says that, and how to maybe fix it?

I have seen the other questions here on StackOverflow, but they don't seem to solve the problem for me and possibly other too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cx\_Freeze: "No module named 'codecs'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cx_Freeze 5.1, there was a bug that resulted in this error. It has been corrected in the source so if you checkout the latest source and compile it yourself it should work for you. If not, let me know!