# How can I make an executable for python3 if I am using PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, executable, cx-freeze

I tried to make the executable with cxFreeze, but it sends me the error that it does not find the module called Codecs, could someone help me to create the executable with either cxFreeze or with any other tool?

Comment: Please provide your setup script and some detail as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment your question cannot be answered because it has no details that might help us solve the problem.

Comment: Second [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359677/python-cx-freeze-init-no-module-named-codecs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs-windows-10) seem to relate to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well without further details we can't help much.  However the codecs problem is common in cx_Freeze and this was fixed in the latest version.  You should update cx_Freeze to version 5.1 and your problem should be fixed.

Source:  https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/325