# cx_Freeze isn't working

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm a newbie to `cx_Freeze`, so I tried to make an executable for a program (I'm trying to make a compiler) that uses a the module `sys` with this setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

    },

}

setup(
    name = "<any name>",
    options = options,
    version = "0.1",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

I'm using python 3.5, and when I open the generated `.exe` throws me this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
```

How i can fix that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cx\_Freeze ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738236/cx-freeze-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-codecs)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your cx_freeze version to the latest and this error will be fixed.  See:

[cx_Freeze: “No module named 'codecs'” Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs-windows-10)

[cx_Freeze ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738236/cx-freeze-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-codecs?rq=1)